# How would you design a PDA to recognize the language of binary strings that end with a different symbol than they start with?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar

How would you design a PDA (Push Down Automata) to recognize the language of binary strings that end with a different symbol than they start with?
This can be a description or a diagrammatic state machine

Comment: It appears that a finite-state machine is sufficient to solve the problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elaborating on Parcly Taxel's comment, your language is $0\{0,1\}^*1 \cup 1\{0,1\}^*0$ and hence is regular. You should be able to find the minimal deterministic automaton of this language. Hint: you need 5 states.